# Spin of hydrogen orthonormal

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, hydrogen

In [this video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRSI4hft0DY&list=PLm8ZSArAXicL3jKr_0nHHs5TwfhdkMFhh&index=76), the lecturer wrote spin up is $|\alpha\rangle = [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ and spin-down is $|\beta\rangle= [\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}]$.

He then wrote that $\langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle = 1$ and $\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle = 0$

But I'm thinking that $\langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle = \alpha \cdot \alpha = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$ ?

Above I'm basically taking the dot product.

Can someone explain what I'm getting wrong?

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >.

Comment: @Jakob Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology $|\alpha\rangle = |1/2,1/2\rangle$ does *not* mean that this is a two-element vector with components 1/2 and 1/2. Instead, the first element refers to the total spin $s=1/2$, and the second element refers to the $z$-component of the spin.  These are just *labels* for the state that correspond to eigenvalues of the spin operators.  Thus, these are the *quantum numbers* of the state.  The state as written is *assumed* to be the *normalized* eigenvector of those operators with the corresponding eigenvalues, i.e.
$$\hat{S}^2|1/2,1/2\rangle = \hbar^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\right)|1/2,1/2\rangle,
$$
and
$$\hat{S}_z|1/2,1/2\rangle = \hbar\frac{1}{2}|1/2,1/2\rangle.
$$

Comment: So is $\langle \alpha | \alpha \rangle = \delta_{i, j}$ really implying that the wavefunction, regardless of the other parameters $(n, l, m_l)$, is kronecker delta? And really they just left the other parameters $n, l, m_l$ out of the math? Should I assume $| \alpha \rangle$ is really $| n, l, m_l, \alpha \rangle$ for ANY $n, l, m_l$ in the identity $\langle \alpha | \alpha \rangle = \delta_{i, j}$? $\langle n,l,m, \alpha | n,l,m, \alpha \rangle = \delta_{i, j}$

Comment: $\langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle=1$, not a kronecker delta, because these are the same state. The full hydrogen wave function is $|nlm\alpha\rangle$ which can be interpreted as a *product* $|nlm\rangle|\alpha\rangle$, where spin operators only hit the $|\alpha\rangle$ part and spatial operators only hit the $|nlm\rangle$ part. Your use of $\delta_{ij}$ is incorrect. $\langle nlm\alpha|nlm\alpha\rangle=1$, but $\langle n'l'm'\alpha'|nml\alpha\rangle = \delta_{ll'}\delta_{nn'}\delta_{mm'}\delta_{\alpha\alpha'}$. I.e., if any two of the quantum numbers are different, the inner product is zero.

Comment: What is the actual function defined by $| \alpha \rangle$ ? I think we are really saying there is some function $f(s, m_s)$ that has the property $\langle f(s, m) | f(s, m')\rangle = \delta_{mm'}$. But I have never actually seen anyone write out this function ever.

Comment: You can *kind of* think of $|\alpha\rangle$ as a $\alpha(\sigma)$, where $\sigma$ takes on only two possible values (1/2 and -1/2), and $\alpha(\sigma)$ is the amplitude for the state being in state $|1/2\rangle$. We're abusing an mixing up notation a little bit. Generally speaking, $|\alpha\rangle = c_1|1/2,{-1/2}\rangle+c_2|1/2,{1/2}\rangle$, and the relationship to the function language is $\alpha(-1/2) = c_1$ and $\alpha(1/2)\c_2$. It's easier to just think of $|alpha\rangle$ as a vector in 2D vector space.

Answer (score 0):

How are you taking a dot product? Regarding the ket $|s, m_s\rangle$ the quantity $s^2 + m_s^2$ does mean anything.

The Hilbert space for the spin of a spin $\frac 1 2$ fermion is two dimensional. The basis states are:

$$|s=\frac 1 2,m_s=+\frac 1 2\rangle $$
$$|s=\frac 1 2,m_s=-\frac 1 2\rangle $$

which are commonly called "spin up" and "spin down", respectively. They are orthonormal, so that:

$$ \langle \frac 1 2, m|\frac 1 2, m'\rangle= \delta_{mm'}$$

(note that $s$ is always $\frac 1 2$).

A general pure state can be written as:

$$ |\chi\rangle = \alpha|\frac 1 2, +\frac 1 2\rangle+\beta|\frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2\rangle$$

where $\alpha,\beta$ are complex numbers in the unit disk. Note that $\chi$ is normalized so that:

$$ \langle \chi|\chi\rangle =
\big[
\alpha^*\langle \frac 1 2,+\frac 1 2|+\beta^*\langle \frac 1 2,-\frac 1 2|
\big]
\big[\alpha|\frac 1 2, +\frac 1 2\rangle+\beta|\frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2\rangle\big]\equiv 1$$

or

$$\alpha^*\alpha\langle \frac 1 2, +\frac 1 2|\frac 1 2, +\frac 1 2\rangle + 
\alpha^*\beta\langle \frac 1 2, +\frac 1 2|\frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2\rangle + 
\beta^*\alpha\langle \frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2|\frac 1 2, +\frac 1 2\rangle + 
\beta^*\beta\langle \frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2|\frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2\rangle=1$$

Apply the orthonormality conditions:

$$|\alpha|^2 +|\beta|^2= 1$$

so that you can write them in terms of real angles:

$$ \alpha= \cos{\frac{\theta}2}$$
$$ \beta= \sin{\frac{\theta}2}e^{i\phi}$$

(note an overall global phase has been factored out make $\alpha$ real). In this form, the Hilbert space is referred to as The Bloch Sphere.

If the bra-ket notation is too abstract, one can write a mathematical representation of the general state as:

$$ \chi = \left[\begin{array}{c}\alpha\\\beta\end{array}\right]$$

The spin up/down states are eigenvectors of:

$$ \hat S_z = \left[\begin{array}{cc}+\frac 1 2 & 0 \\0&-\frac 1 2\end{array}\right]$$

with eigenvalue $\pm \frac 1 2 $. The orthonormality relations are then straight forward.

All states are eigenstates of total angular momentum squared ($\hbar=1$):

$$ \hat S^2 = \left[\begin{array}{cc}\frac 3 4 & 0 \\0&\frac 3 4\end{array}\right]$$

with eigenvalue:

$$\lambda = s(s+1) = \frac 1 2(\frac 1 2 + 1)= \frac 3 4$$

Note the state $\chi$ is the "wave function", though it's usually called a "state" because, unlike $\psi(x)$, it's not defined over a continuous (position) variable, which is how we usually think of function.

Comment: If hydrogen radial function is $Re(n, l, r)$ and spherical harmonics is $Y(l, m_l, \theta, \Phi)$ then is $|n, l, m_l, m_s \rangle = Re * Y * |s, m_s> $? If so, what is the function $|s, m_s>$ ? I think I need to see a proof of how $\langle \frac{1}{2}, m | \frac{1}{2}, m' \rangle = \delta_{mm'}$ before I really understand this.

Comment: @Frank The Hilbert space is the Bloch Sphere, which describes any two state quantum system. There are no functions of position, as there is no position.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ aren't coordinates, they're labels. If they label an orthonormal basis, then: $\langle a,b|a',b'\rangle = \delta_{aa'}\delta_{bb'}$, by definition. E.g in a 2d infinite square well, you can label eigenstates with $a=(1,2,\ldots)$ and $b=(1,2,\ldots)$, then instead of writing $\psi(x,y)=\frac 1 {N_{ab}} \sin(a\pi x/L)\sin(b\pi y/L)$ you just call it $|a,b\rangle$.

Comment: Hi I deleted that because this video explained it to me. I can consider spin up like (1, 0) and spin down like (0, 1) vectors: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWM0RXg-uvI

Comment: No to delete questions. I had added the vector form already. I think it's better to learn them 1st, before going abstract with bra-ket. Nevertheless, the vector space in which those column vectors live is pretty abstract.